# java.io.NotSerializableException when sending an object containing a JAXB element

Tags: java, apache, jaxb, queue, activemq-classic

I'm facing a problem when sending an object through ActiveMQ to a queue. The object I send is a BrokerRequest and it contains an UUID, a priority (1,2,3) and a DocumentType which is a JAXB object.

Here's the block of code I'm using:

```
DocumentType jaxbDoc = getJaxbFromFile("/home/dev/document.xml");
BrokerRequest brokerRequest = new BrokerRequest(UUID.randomUUID(), 1, jaxbDoc);
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();       
            connection.start();
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Destination destination = session.createQueue(topic);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
            ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(brokerRequest);
            producer.send(objectMessage);
            connection.close();
```

The method "getJaxbFromFile" receives the path in which I have an xml document representing this Jaxb type, what I do in that method is unmarshall that xml into the Jaxb DocumentType to include it inside my BrokerRequest object.

But I receive this exception of notSerializable whenever I try to send the objectMessage to the broker, but all the elements involved in the JaxB are serializable, that's why I don't understand why I'm receiving this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: jaxb.mapped.elements.xsd.commons.MonetaryTotalType
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.storeContent(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:111)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.setObject(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:162)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createObjectMessage(ActiveMQSession.java:381)
    at efact.alfa1lab.test.commons.MessageUtils.putMessageOnBroker(MessageUtils.java:184)
    at test.commons.MessageUtils.main(MessageUtils.java:97)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: jaxb.mapped.elements.xsd.commons.MonetaryTotalType
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQObjectMessage.storeContent(ActiveMQObjectMessage.java:105)
```

I will really appreciate if somebody could help me and I'll be grateful if somebody could give me a clue about this issue.

==============================
The code for the MonetaryType is the following:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.AllowanceTotalAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.ChargeTotalAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.LineExtensionAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.PayableAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.PayableRoundingAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.PrepaidAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.TaxExclusiveAmountType;
import oasis.names.specification.ubl.schema.xsd.commonbasiccomponents_2.TaxInclusiveAmountType;


/**
 * 
 *         
 * <pre>
 * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;ABIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Details&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;Information about Monetary Totals.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;
 *         &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
 * </pre>
 * 
 *       
 * 
 * <p>Java class for MonetaryTotalType complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="MonetaryTotalType">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}LineExtensionAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}TaxExclusiveAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}TaxInclusiveAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}AllowanceTotalAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}ChargeTotalAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}PrepaidAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}PayableRoundingAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element ref="{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2}PayableAmount"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MonetaryTotalType", propOrder = {
    "lineExtensionAmount",
    "taxExclusiveAmount",
    "taxInclusiveAmount",
    "allowanceTotalAmount",
    "chargeTotalAmount",
    "prepaidAmount",
    "payableRoundingAmount",
    "payableAmount"
})
public class MonetaryTotalType implements Serializable {


    @XmlElement(name = "LineExtensionAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected LineExtensionAmountType lineExtensionAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "TaxExclusiveAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected TaxExclusiveAmountType taxExclusiveAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "TaxInclusiveAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected TaxInclusiveAmountType taxInclusiveAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "AllowanceTotalAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected AllowanceTotalAmountType allowanceTotalAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "ChargeTotalAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected ChargeTotalAmountType chargeTotalAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "PrepaidAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected PrepaidAmountType prepaidAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "PayableRoundingAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2")
    protected PayableRoundingAmountType payableRoundingAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "PayableAmount", namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2", required = true)
    protected PayableAmountType payableAmount;

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Line Extension Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total of Line Extension Amounts net of tax and settlement discounts, but inclusive of any applicable rounding amount.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Line Extension Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link LineExtensionAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public LineExtensionAmountType getLineExtensionAmount() {
        return lineExtensionAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the lineExtensionAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link LineExtensionAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setLineExtensionAmount(LineExtensionAmountType value) {
        this.lineExtensionAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Tax Exclusive Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total amount exclusive of taxes.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Tax Exclusive Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link TaxExclusiveAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public TaxExclusiveAmountType getTaxExclusiveAmount() {
        return taxExclusiveAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the taxExclusiveAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link TaxExclusiveAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setTaxExclusiveAmount(TaxExclusiveAmountType value) {
        this.taxExclusiveAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Tax Inclusive Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total amount inclusive of taxes.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Tax Inclusive Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link TaxInclusiveAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public TaxInclusiveAmountType getTaxInclusiveAmount() {
        return taxInclusiveAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the taxInclusiveAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link TaxInclusiveAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setTaxInclusiveAmount(TaxInclusiveAmountType value) {
        this.taxInclusiveAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Allowance Total Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total amount of all allowances.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Allowance Total Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link AllowanceTotalAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public AllowanceTotalAmountType getAllowanceTotalAmount() {
        return allowanceTotalAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the allowanceTotalAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link AllowanceTotalAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setAllowanceTotalAmount(AllowanceTotalAmountType value) {
        this.allowanceTotalAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Charge Total Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total amount of all charges.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Charge Total Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link ChargeTotalAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public ChargeTotalAmountType getChargeTotalAmount() {
        return chargeTotalAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the chargeTotalAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link ChargeTotalAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setChargeTotalAmount(ChargeTotalAmountType value) {
        this.chargeTotalAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Prepaid Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total prepaid amount.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Prepaid Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link PrepaidAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public PrepaidAmountType getPrepaidAmount() {
        return prepaidAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the prepaidAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link PrepaidAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setPrepaidAmount(PrepaidAmountType value) {
        this.prepaidAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Payable_ Rounding Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The rounding amount (positive or negative) added to the calculated Line Extension Total Amount to produce the rounded Line Extension Total Amount.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;0..1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTermQualifier&gt;Payable&lt;/ccts:PropertyTermQualifier&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Rounding Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link PayableRoundingAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public PayableRoundingAmountType getPayableRoundingAmount() {
        return payableRoundingAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the payableRoundingAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link PayableRoundingAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setPayableRoundingAmount(PayableRoundingAmountType value) {
        this.payableRoundingAmount = value;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *             
     * <pre>
     * &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;ccts:Component xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;ccts:ComponentType&gt;BBIE&lt;/ccts:ComponentType&gt;&lt;ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;Monetary Total. Payable_ Amount. Amount&lt;/ccts:DictionaryEntryName&gt;&lt;ccts:Definition&gt;The total amount to be paid.&lt;/ccts:Definition&gt;&lt;ccts:Cardinality&gt;1&lt;/ccts:Cardinality&gt;&lt;ccts:ObjectClass&gt;Monetary Total&lt;/ccts:ObjectClass&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTermQualifier&gt;Payable&lt;/ccts:PropertyTermQualifier&gt;&lt;ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:PropertyTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;Amount&lt;/ccts:RepresentationTerm&gt;&lt;ccts:DataType&gt;Amount. Type&lt;/ccts:DataType&gt;
     *             &lt;/ccts:Component&gt;
     * </pre>
     * 
     *           
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link PayableAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public PayableAmountType getPayableAmount() {
        return payableAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the payableAmount property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link PayableAmountType }
     *     
     */
    public void setPayableAmount(PayableAmountType value) {
        this.payableAmount = value;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your unmarshalling the XML file to custom classes, one of which is of type `jaxb.mapped.elements.xsd.commons.MonetaryTotalType`. This class is not serializable, causing the exception to be thrown. Usually you should be fine marking the class as serializable by implementing `Serializable` interface.

Also, consider using package names prefixed using your product or at least company name; having a root package called `jaxb` is confusing because it isn't immediately apparent that is your own code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what you said makes sense, but the fact is that all the types used by my XML are implementing the Serializable Interface, when I generate all the types using the schema, all of them were generated implementing Serializable. That's why I don't understand how to solve the problem. What is very curious is that this functionality runs in a production environment, but not in my development pc. I tried sending just a new instance of  DocumentType(), and when I run the app, it works, but when I use "setMonetaryTotalType()" it shows me the same error. Thank you so much

Comment: Could you post the source code of `MonetaryTotalType`? Also, is the production environment exactly the same (versions, etc.) as your development PC?

Comment: I will post the code of the MonetaryTotalType by editing the original post since, the comment textbox does not allow me to put more than 500 characters. I have to mention that I removed this MonetaryTotalType from my DocumentType, but then, I get the same exception for another Jaxb element which is the IDType. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit in the dark as to what is happening here. Are you very sure there's no other `MonetaryTotalType` on your classpath? The source code you posted doesn't mention the `jaxb.mapped.elements.xsd.commons` package anywhere.

Comment: At first I thought that was the error, I thought that it was another MonetaryTotalType in my classpath, that's why I renamed the package to "jaxb.mapped.elements.xsd.commons", but the original name is the one that appears in my source code. I ensured there's no other class of the same type. It is pretty strange for me too, thanks for your support, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would start looking for any differences between the production and development environment, because if the same code works in production there's definitely something funny going on. For now there's nothing else that comes to mind (unfortunately).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will look for any mismatch in both codes, that funny thing is driving me crazy, but I will find it, thanks for your help and interest. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My serializable object had an unserializable  member object variable. After making it implement serializable the error went away.